# to film a video

Tags: expressions

I know that "to film" can be used transitively or intransitively. Example of transitive usages:

[The cast and crew have been filming this movie for a year.](https://www.wordreference.com/definition/film)

[It took them six weeks to film the documentary.](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/film_2)

Given that "to film a documentary" and "to film a movie" are valid usages of the verb "to film", is "to film a video" wrong/not usual? I have read so in https://forum.duolingo.com/comment/20856372 , but I am not sure it is right.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wM_oXbkqM8U ...so I suppose it can be used. I don't know how common/usual it is.

Comment: Even though we don't use a photographic film to record a 'video', we can still use the verb 'to film'. You can use 'shoot' or 'make' if you want.

Comment: Netflix is making a drama series in which some of the exterior scenes are done in my street in Bristol, UK, and everyone in the street has had a letter apologising for the inconvenience (huge trucks, lots of crew, etc), and they make prolific use of 'film', and 'filming', even though I am quite sure (I have seen them) they use digital electronic cameras. Not a Kodak logo to be seen.